# Google Cloud Node js deployment issue : (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9]

Tags: node.js, angular, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am new to Angular and I am trying to build a basic HelloWorld program to deploy to Google Cloud. However, I am getting the exception shown below.

These are the steps I have taken:

1. I have installed NVM, which uses npm version 5.6.0 and the Google Cloud client.
2. I have created the HelloWorld application using the `ng new` command.
3. Inside my project I have run the `ng build --prod` command.
4. Finally, I run `gcloud app deploy` command to deploy the HelloWorld application.

After all those steps, this is the error I am getting:

```
> my-app@0.0.0 start /app
> ng serve

sh: 1: ng: not found
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! my-app@0.0.0 start: `ng serve`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the my-app@0.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2018-04-24T17_23_25_110Z-debug.log
```

Please suggest what to do next.

Answer (score 1):

Firtsly install angular cli

Use this command : npm install -g angular-cli
then try again hope it will work.

Answer (score 1):

I just had an error like this during deployment , (it was a rimraf not found error) and to solve that I just copy my devdependencies and add it in my dependencies in package.json file. I don't know If it is the right thing to do but it works for me !
Hope it helps someone

Answer (score 0):

Since you are new to using Angular and you want to know how to deploy your Angular application to Google Cloud, here is a [tutorial](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-cardboard-viewer) that may be helpful for you. It includes an example of an Angular application you can use as a reference to develop your own app. Just in case, I will also include an [example](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/getting-started/hello-world) on how to deploy a HelloWorld application using Node.js.

You can focus on the parts related to preparing the right setup, testing the sample application and deploying it to Google Cloud.

To put it simple, in your application's root directory, where files such as `app.yaml` should be, you can run the following commands to prepare and test your application locally:

```
$ npm install
$ npm start
```

In the Cloud Shell, hit the web preview icon (the one that looks like a square eye) and select "Preview on port 8080" to check if the test application works.

If the test is successful, your next step would be to deploy the application into Google Cloud by running this:

```
$ gcloud app deploy
```

Once the deploy is finished, run this command to check if the deploy is correct:

```
$ gcloud app browse
```

It will point you to the address where your application is running, and check if the deployment has been successful.